# Display present SQLite databases on listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to get all databases present on my Android phone programatically and                                                                                                       display those all on listview, but I could not get any solution.

I got this code from Google, but it doesn't show all present databases on listview.

```
private ArrayList<String> getDBFILES() 
{
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    String db_path, rand_name, str_tmp;

    //ad.1-2. random file name for db

    rand_name = new Random().nextInt((4000000-2000+1)+2000)+".db";
    db_path = openOrCreateDatabase(rand_name, MODE_PRIVATE, null).getPath();

    //ad.3.
    deleteDatabase(rand_name);

    //ad.4.
    db_path = db_path.replace("/" + rand_name, "");

    //ad.5.
    File [] files = new File(db_path).listFiles();
    if (files == null) { return null; }

    //so now we get the filenames one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    { 
       str_tmp = files[i].getName();
       if (!str_tmp.endsWith("-journal"))
          {  arr.add(str_tmp); }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Does "all" mean "all of your app", or "all, including all other apps, and the system"?

Comment: As far as I know, you will need permissions to read from the /data/data directory which are not opened as standard. Are you rooted?

Comment: i got it but how i implement it in my coding can u help please.if you have some code then can you give it to me

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't! you only can access to your app databases! If you have more than one application you still can access databases from your other apps using some trikes! (running all of them under the same sandbox) 

although you have not permission to access other apps databases some applications (including android system itself) provided content providers. you can not directly manipulate the database but you can use the content provider for each app that eventually runs query on the database.

Comment: i got it but how i implement it in my coding can u help please.if you have some code then can you give it to me.

Comment: hello alireza. as you say i can use content provider.. but please if you dont mind give me some code....i wasted my 2 days on that i still facing this problem.

Comment: I didn't worked with content providers before so i can not give you precise answer or any code because i don't have any! You can read professional android application development.this book describes how to use contact content provider and also explains how to build a content provider for your app. also visit http://goo.gl/8U58YY it may be a good place to start. good luck